# Convert int value to res/color

Tags: android, colors, android-resources

This may be a very specific question because I didn't find anything related.
Also, sorry if I couldn't find a better title.

I'm working with android colors, specifically, I'm in a situation where I need to let the user programmatically change color of a view.

I'll give some values and example so that you can undestand better my case.

In my `res/colors.xml` I have this color_green with value `#4CAF50`.
As soon as the activity starts, I set this color to a view.
In order so set the color,I'm first converting it to a String hex color as:

```
int color = myGreenColor; // This is directly taken from resource so R.color.green_color, (2131427355)
int value = ContextCompat.getColor(context, color); // (-11751600)
String hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (value)); // (#FF4CAF50)
```

then I set it to the view with

`mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(hexColor));`// (-11751600) again

Now, the `myGreenColor` value is changed as the user pick another color from the pes8 `ColorPicker` library found [at this link](https://github.com/Pes8/android-material-color-picker-dialog)

Let's say I pick the exact same value which I pass to the constructor of the library in R, G, B ints.

If I print the returned value from the dialog, I get something like

```
-11751600.
```

Which I couldn't fit into any `set`, `parse` or other method.
That said, how can I convert this value in order to work with the previous conversions?

I need to convert from format `-11751600` to format `2131427355`. or any other intermediate step value.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the RGB values you can directly do this to :

```
String color = "#" + RR + GG + BB;
```

Then set this color to your view using

```
mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color))
```

`Color.parseColor(String)` supports #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB format colors. You can check the documentation here [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Color.html#parseColor(java.lang.String))